# npm commands are throwing error

Tags: npm, nodes

I have installed nodejs and also have "package.json" in my application.
But every npm command is throwing following error in console:

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at evalmachine.<anonymous>:31:26
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SattikaA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

I've tried to remove and reinstall latest nodejs version; still problem remains the same.

Comment: seems its a known issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19063 you can try downgrading to a stable version.

Answer (score 0):

not load from node_module folder, it need begin with './', '../' or '/'。more detail on https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules